# How to make case join statement by using activerecord

Tags: codeigniter

I have two different table.
(1)dog_breeds
(2)cat_breeds

now in the third table, I have column name pet_cat. Now I want to join with dog_breeds if pet_cat == 1 else join with cat_breeds. How can I do this just by using CodeIgniter active record.

Comment: Nice question but you can't do some complex things in active record. Sometimes you must writr sql codes. I'm thinking now and will write the solution.

Comment: use codeigniter join()